# What is the difference between callout and HTTP request?

Tags: callout, http

I don't quite understand those concepts. Are they the same?

Answer (score 7):

No, that's nor quite right. Imagine **callout** as *animal* and **Http** as *cat*, it's a subclass, not the actual class.

What I mean is you have 2 types of callouts in Apex:

```
Http http = new Http();
http.send(/*...*/);
```

and

```
WebServiceCallout.invoke(/*...*/);
```

Here is the [documentation link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts.htm).